# user.save() does not save (does nothing) in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to save a user in MongoDB, but it doesn't seem to work. I have no idea why. All i can tell you is that, the code is running and going in the .pre save function but it doesn't enter in the save function promise.

Can you tell me why it is not saving in base ?

**Front submit function**

```
handleSubmit(user){
    console.log(user);
    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/signup', user)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            console.log("OBVIOUSLY I DON'T SEE THIS LOG EITHER");
        }
    );
}
```

**app.js (node.js file)**

```
app.post('/signup', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
let user = new User(req.body);
user.save().then(() => {
    console.log("I DON'T SEE THIS LOG");
});
res.end();
});
```

**user.js (node.js file)**

```
UserSchema.pre("save", (next) => {
console.log(this);
console.log("I SEE THIS LOG");
next();
});
const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe a stupid question, but isn't your User in app.js undefined ?
maybe console.log the req.body. because i do not think you are making a user to begin with.

**another tip :**
use mongoose's create function instead, you will find a example under construction documents:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Comment: I'm importing my User model in the app.js file via this line of code :const User = require('./models/user');

Comment: the req.body is a JSON of my object, that i submit in my front form

Comment: let user = new User(req.body).save(); maybe this will work , otherwise try my tip i edited in.

Comment: I'm so sorry, i just wasn't connecting to my bdd with mongoose. That's why it couldn't saved ......

Comment: this made me chuckle but hey, atleast you know now why it didnt work. good luck any further.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `.then()` on your `app.js` try using a callback.

```
user.save(function(err, res){ 
          if (err){throw err;} 
           console.log('test me', res)
         })
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. No error,and no log is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your request before the `user` being saved.

move the `res.end()` into `then` function to solve the problem.

Or you can make an `async function(req, res)` and put `await` before `user.save()`, remove `then` and wait for database to response, like below:

```
app.post('/signup', urlencodedParser, async function(req, res) {
  let user = new User(req.body);
  await user.save();
  res.end();
});
```